# Using gzip in Meteor

Tags: node.js, meteor, gzip

Right now I'm working on a project where I need to use any meteor or nodejs module for decoding response from a server whose content-encoding is gzip. Actually, I need jpeg image file from the server but it returned binary codes of the jpeg image file which needs to be decoded.

So, anybody who has any example for this will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try searching on npmjs.org? There seem to be quite a few.  I haven't had this problem, so I don't know which work well.  Example: https://www.npmjs.org/package/zlibjs

Comment: I used zlib npm package but it throws errors in Meteor. Do you have any example which can point me inright direction.

Comment: How are you retrieving the data from the server? gzip compression is usually done on the fly, and if your http client for retrieving the data doesn't understand gzip compression, then you should indicate that in the headers you are sending with the request.

Comment: Ok i solved this myself. Actually I used node's request package with pipe(fs.createWriteStream('image_name.ext')) which stored requested image file. Anyway thanks for your consideration.

Answer (score 7):

Maybe a bit late, Meteor enables gzip on default, but only for json, javascript and text, check [webapp_server.js](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/webapp/webapp_server.js)

Insides the file, you will see this line:  app.use(connect.compress());

When you look at the [compress](https://github.com/expressjs/compression) package, it has a filter function which determines what should be compressed. So if you want to compress every content (image, music, pdf, etc) served from Meteor, you can add this line to your code:

```
var compression = Npm.require('compression') // in your package.js, need to also add Npm.depends({compression:'1.3.0'})
WebApp.rawConnectHandlers.use(compression({filter: function(){return true}})) //always compress
//WebApp.rawConnectHandlers.use('/images',compression({filter: function(){return true}})) //or only compress files under the images folder
```

However, compression is an expensive process, gzipping images in jpg format may not achieve much because these images are already compressed